# JOptionPane issue using internal dialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, temp);
```

`result` value will be the inputted value.

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(this, temp);
```

`result` value will be null even you inputted a string.

`temp` is a panel that will contain in the JOptionPane. This JOptionPane will show on top of another customized JOptioPane.

Comment: I mean about the output. Why different?

Comment: If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 6):

`JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog` is to be used with `JDesktopPane`/`JInternalFrame`s only, where `this` is the `JDesktopPane`/`JInternalFrame`s instance.

```
final JDesktopPane desk = new JDesktopPane();
...
String s=JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(desk, "Enter Name");
```

If not used with either of the 2 above mentioned components it will not produce the correct output, in fact it will throw a Runtime Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: JOptionPane: parentComponent does not have
>   a valid parent

**UPDATE**

As per your comments here is an example of how you would add `JPanel` to `JDesktopPane` and call `JOptionPane#showInternalInputDialog`. The important part is we need to call `setBounds` and `setVisible` on `JPanel` like we would as if it was `JInternalFrame` being added to the `JDesktopPane`, except of course we are adding a `JPanel`

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("JInternalFrame Usage Demo");

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

// A specialized layered pane to be used with JInternalFrames
jdpDesktop = new JDesktopPane() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(600, 600);
    }
};

frame.setContentPane(jdpDesktop);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);

jdpDesktop.add(panel);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

panel.setVisible(true);

String result = JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog(jdpDesktop, "h");

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: 1+. You're probably right, and I shudder every time I see `this` as a parameter for one of these methods as it suggests that @Juan has made the mistake of needlessly having his class extend JFrame or some other top-level GUI window.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels very good investigation skills and most likely correct.

Comment: @JuanMatanong please see my edit. `showInternalInputDialog` is to only be used with `JDesktopPane`s/`JInternalFrame`s or it will not work (i.e no optionpane will be shown and exception is thrown)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, im just working on a `JPanel` class. How can I put it to a `JDesktopPane/JInternalFrame`.

Comment: Are you sure you need this? because I cannot see why you'd want to do all that when you can just use `showInputDialog`, which is meant for `JFrame`s, `JPanel`s etc

Comment: I am working on full screen. It is required to use `showInternalInputDialog`.

Comment: @JuanMatanong where did you read that? or do you mean your project states you must use `showInternalInputDialog`?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, my project states i must use it.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, can I add it without using the `JFrame`? Because whenever is use it, my `fullscreen` will be destroyed.

Comment: @JuanMatanong hard to say without code. But as long as it works for you. I'm sure you can just call add() on whatever container and add the desktoppane.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp, this JOptionPane will show on top of another JOptionPane. What should I put on the `JOptionPane` `parentComponent`?

Comment: @JuanMatanong The `jdesktoppane`. did you try it before asking?

Comment: @JuanMatanong thats very vague please edit your question to show an SSCCE as I hate guessing... however If you execute 2 `showInternalXXX` dialogs one after the other, the first call will wait for the other to return as `JOptionPane`s have modality. So try clicking *OK* or whatever to the one that appears, now does your second one appear?