# How to call JinternalFrame from jInternalFrame withut lossing calling frames control in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am calling ABC jINternalFrame from  XYZ jInternalFrame in SWING.

But When I call ABC I am losing XYZcontrol

What I want is

-On XYZ  user selects option to load product data
-IF mismatch found XYZ calls ABC 
-In ABC -user correct mismatch  and closes ABC frame 
Now I want my program should continue from where it called ABC

Currently It calls ABC and XYZ get executed  How I can achieve this ?
And I am using below code

```
if (frmUpdateData == null || frmUpdateData.isClosed()){ 
  frmUpdateData = new FrmUpdateData(); 
  JDesktopPane desktopPane = getDesktopPane(); 
  desktopPane.add(frmUpdateData); 
  frmUpdateData.setVisible(true); 
  frmUpdateData.setLocation(this.getWidth()/2- frmUpdateData.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2-frmUpdateData.getHeight()/2); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking -- please clarify the question for us, but I think that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083517/joptionpane-issue-using-internal-dialog) may be a duplicate, and that you want to use a `JOptionPane.showInternalInputDialog` here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You show use a Modal dialog:

```
final JDialog frame = new JDialog(parentFrame, frameTitle, true);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When you show a modal dialog, the code that called the modal, is waiting for modal dialog to be closed to continue execution. It is like `alert` in JavaScript.

If you **dont** wana use JDialog, you can try this:

```
    JInternalFrame frmUpdateData = null;
    frmUpdateData = new JInternalFrame("Test", true, true);
    frmUpdateData.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
    JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
    desktopPane.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
    desktopPane.add(frmUpdateData);
    desktopPane.setVisible(true);
    frmUpdateData.setVisible(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(desktopPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    while (frmUpdateData != null && !frmUpdateData.isClosed()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done");
```

Reference: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java)

Comment: Hi @Edgard-Leal  I am using this code currently how shold I chnage it to use modal dialog to a jinternal frame `code` if (frmUpdateData == null || frmUpdateData.isClosed()){
frmUpdateData  = new FrmUpdateData();
JDesktopPane desktopPane = getDesktopPane();
desktopPane.add(frmUpdateData);
frmUpdateData.setVisible(true);
frmUpdateData.setLocation(this.getWidth()/2- frmUpdateData.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2-frmUpdateData.getHeight()/2);
} `code`